# Getting HmacSHA1 Java Hash to match Powershell Hash

Tags: java, powershell, hmacsha1

I have this Powershell snippet, which I cannot change and provides the Hash I need to match:

```
$key = 'test'
$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($key)
WRITE-HOST "bytes: " $bytes
$hmacsha = new-object system.security.cryptography.HMACSHA1
$hmacsha.key = $bytes
$hash = $hmacsha.ComputeHash($bytes)
WRITE-HOST "hash: " $hash
```

Which gives this result:

```
bytes:  116 101 115 116
hash:  12 148 81 92 21 229 9 91 138 135 165 11 160 223 59 243 142 208 95 230
```

And this in Java:

```
String key = "test";
byte[] bytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println("bytes: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] keyBytes = md.digest(bytes);
SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(sk);
byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(keyBytes);
System.out.println("hash 1: " + Arrays.toString(hash));

sk = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "HmacSHA1");
mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(sk);
hash = mac.doFinal(bytes);
System.out.println("hash 2: " + Arrays.toString(hash));
```

Which outputs:

```
bytes: [116, 101, 115, 116]
hash 1: [-112, -37, 64, 65, -91, -97, 36, 60, -80, -110, 62, -105, -63, -69, -79, -18, 29, -95, 23, -116]
hash 2: [12, -108, 81, 92, 21, -27, 9, 91, -118, -121, -91, 11, -96, -33, 59, -13, -114, -48, 95, -26]
```

I cannot seem to get the Hash to match what Powershell is outputting. In both examples I am creating a hmacsha1 instance with a key of "test", then getting the hash of "test", but both have some minor difference causing them to give different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting 2 different hashes. Matter of fact ...

```
12, -108, 81, 92, 21, -27, 9, 91, -118, -121, -91, 11, -96, -33, 59, -13, -114, -48, 95, -26
```

is the same as

```
12 148 81 92 21 229 9 91 138 135 165 11 160 223 59 243 142 208 95 230
```

What is happening is in java when you turn to string it is making these values signed.

An example of this is with -108 and 148

```
00000000,10010100 = 148
11111111,10010100 = -108
```

If you want to make the byte look unsigned you can use 0xFF combined with the byte.

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("148");
System.out.println(b);
```

outputs : **-108**

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("148");
System.out.println(b & 0xFF);
```

outputs : **148**

What is happening is you are usinga bitwise AND operator
so 0xFF = 255 aka 11111111 and matching common bits and keeping them.

```
00000000,11111111 = 255 aka 0xFF
11111111,10010100 = -108
--------
00000000,10010100 = 148
```